# How to call setState properly?

Tags: reactjs

Hello tell me the best practice please!

I need two simple action, get data from API, and set data to state. I read I can do API request in componentDidMount, but in this function I can't set state.

Actually all work good if I do this way, but if I try reload page, I got this error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getData();
}

getData = async () => {
  try {
    // Get data from api
    const fund = await axios.get(
      APIEnpoint + "api/smartfund/" + this.props.match.params.address
    );
    this.setState({
      smartFundAddress: fund.data.result.address,
      name: fund.data.result.name,
      balance: JSON.parse(fund.data.result.balance)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
    alert(`can't get data`);
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I read I can do API request in componentDidMount, but in this function I can't set state." Yes, you can. You could make `componentDidMount` async and put all the logic there if you prefer. `async componentDidMount() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to set your state after your component has been unmounted. So to prevent it for happening try this one:

```
    _isMounted = false;

    componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

getData = async () => {
  try {
    // Get data from api
    const fund = await axios.get(
      APIEnpoint + "api/smartfund/" + this.props.match.params.address
    );
    if(this._isMounted)
    {
        this.setState({
            smartFundAddress: fund.data.result.address,
            name: fund.data.result.name,
            balance: JSON.parse(fund.data.result.balance)
          });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
    alert(`can't get data`);
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

So if the component is unmounted that will not try to update the state

Comment: but the actual ques is, how component is getting unmount after making an api call in didMount?

Comment: @MayankShukla check if `componentWillUnmount()` is getting called. If not, then check if any other component is getting unmounted and trying to set some kind of state

Comment: Oh I got it, Thank You!